# Book/Movie where criminal is punished in a stadium by focused thoughts

Tags: story-identification, movie, crime

Forgive me if this sounds like a vague question, but I remember in school once, our teacher told us about a book or movie where a criminal is taken into a stadium and is punished by the focused energy of the whole stadium of people directing their thoughts onto him.

Does anyone know the name of the book or movie?? It sounded interesting!

Comment: I remember reading this. There was a stadium speaker who was directing the crowd, "now focus on his left arm, I want you to burn the flesh off it", something like that. No clue to the name or the author, I'm sorry. Maybe I'll remember later.

Comment: @SQB yes, that definitely sounds like what he was talking about, I remember him mentioning burning flesh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the short story "[The Public Hating](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Public_Hating.html?id=GVNfAAAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)" by Steve Allen, published in his 1955 short story collection "Fourteen for Tonight".

And it was his right arm.

[image]

### Further reading

- Joseph D. Olander & Martin H. Greenberg (1977).  [*Criminal Justice Through SF*](http://omphalosbookreviews.com/index.php/reviews/info/315).  Omphalos' SF Book Reviews.
- Mitchell Lopate (2010-10-26). [*"The Public Hating" - a lesson in execution*](http://tccwrite.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/public-hating-lesson-in-execution.html).  The Creative Classroom.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, that's more obscure than I thought it'd be, but I'll try to find it.